# Checking if checkbox in a listView is checked

Tags: qt

I've created a model which displays list of checkable strings in a listView. I don't know how to check if those strings shown in listView are checked || not. Anyone have any idea how to go about it?
EDIT:

```
class File_List_Model : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QStringList files_;//here I'm storing files selected by user
};
```

and in my dialog class called Line_Counter I have a fnc:

```
void Line_Counter::add_files()
{
    QStringList selected_files = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames();//here I'm getting those files

    if (selected_files.size())
    {
        model_->setData(QModelIndex(),selected_files);//here I'm adding them to my model
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect(pointerToYourItem, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), pointerToYourWindow, SLOT(somefunc(bool)));

Comment: hi, do you mean by pointerToYourItem my model responsible for storing and reacting with listView?

Comment: okay, the easiest method to do this is to create QCheckListItem for each string and then add them to your ListView(look for docs for more information about this class)
Then you'll do something like connect(checkBox1, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), model_, SLOT(somefunc(bool))); , where checkBox1 is pointer to your QCheckListItem

Comment: there is a problem with QCheckListItem though.

Comment: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?202070-QListWidget-with-checkbox#post741983 look for this thread, I think this is what you need

Comment: can I still use model view approach with ListWidget? I thought there are unsuitable for this approach, what you're thinking?

Comment: I've never used this method, so you must just try. ;)

Comment: would you know what happened with QCheckListItem in Qt4?

Comment: There's an article for Qt 3.3, so I think it's outdated now